# Weird rigging deformity

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have just completed my model and I am trying to rig it but having some issues.
Most of the times I would just allow Blender to auto rig it which is what I did and it usually works but for some reason this time I am having issues with some parts of the body looking odd when moving its rig.
I've tried many times to mess with the weight paint tool but it seems like that is not working well either.
[Hyperlink of a video on how it looks when moving its rig.](https://youtu.be/ABQw2zAnuLo?si=PBcC4WvmQk2CBd11)
[image: pose mode]

[image: weight paint view]

[image: pose mode ditto]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hello, make sure that the Subdivision Surface modifier is under the Armature modifier, maybe also recalculate the normals in Edit mode. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: To me that's typically what happens when you have multiple bones fighting for influence over the same mesh parts.  I bet the red part in your arm is also painted in other neighboring bones, like the shoulders.  In weight paint, use the menu weights > Normalize All to quickly salve all fighting weights. Then enable auto normalize in your brush settings, test deformations everywhere and paint the groups that need more influence.

Comment: @L0Lock Thank you for telling me about the Normalize option. It fixed my issue!